# OAuth service and official client support

Tags: python, api, authentication, oauth

I'm trying to understand OAuth, and I'm having a hard time figuring this basic thing out...

I have developed a service (with Python and Flask), which supports classic authentification through a dedicated login & password combination, and an "official" client in the form of a webapp. I would like my service to support OAuth and looked into [flask-oauthprovider](https://github.com/ib-lundgren/flask-oauthprovider), which seems like a perfect fit for this task, but I can't seem to understand how everything should articulate.

My questions are:

1. Today, all my API entry points required the user to be logged in: once my service supports OAuth, should every entry points become "oauth_required" rather than "login_required"?
2. What is the proper way to support my "official" webapp front-end? I'd rather not have it go through the regular OAuth flow (with the extra redirections to login on the service). Should it go through OAuth with automatically granted access tokens, or should it bypass OAuth and directly use the "resource owner" login & password?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the problems with the concept behind oauthlib is that it tries too hard to be everything and the result is a difficult-to-reason-about set of abstractions (this is very similar to the python-oauth2 approach). OAuth providers in particular are tricky because you implicitly need to persist things like tokens not to mention the assumption of some kind of pre-exisiting user management. As such a "good" or idiomatic implementation tends to be more opinionated from framework to framework. In my opinion this is part of why we don't see a single Python OAuth provider implementation as an abstraction: there just aren't great solutions, but plenty of messy ones. Looking at flask-oauthprovider and we see some direct examples of these issues. I've had similar problems with flask-login, which I maintain. At any rate, this past weekend I wrote a very rough first pass of a [OAuth provider in Flask](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-simpleoauth) that "just works"; feel free to take a look and adapt it to your needs. It assumes some things like, like MongoDB but with minimal work I think any datastore could be used.

1) Protect whichever endpoints you want to be accessible via a third-party, e.g. your public API.

2) I would avoid automatic access tokens, that defeats the person of negotiating authorization on a per-user basis, unless of course you have a different scheme, e.g. a predefined set of clients. I believe the second option you're talking about is xauth, in which case, why not just use OAuth 2.0 and grant_type=password? Bearer tokens are similar in concept but may be a little easier to implement so long as you can provide HTTPS.